# how to apply texture paint

Tags: texture-baking, texture-painting

[image]

I drawn his eyes and mouth in texture paint and saved the image as png file
[image]

However when I go to layout, my drawing disappears.
How do I apply texture paint to my character?

Comment: Is this Texture Paint or Grease Pencil? You don't appear to have a texture on your object, but the strokes look like Grease Pencil object.

Answer (score 1):

1. You first need to create the `UVs`
2. Than you need to unwrap your `UVs`
3. Than enter Enter `Edit-Mode`
4. Than select  the base of the neck in a loop at the base using edges
5. Than press <kbd>CTRL+E</kbd> `> Edge Data > Mark Seam`
6. Than `Unselect All` all selections
7. Now make an edge selection starting from the base of the neck (in the middle of the loop you just selected but starting at the middle of the neck, and select edges all the way up to the top of the head)
8. Than <kbd>CTRL+E</kbd> `> Mark Edges`
9. `Select All` all selections
10. <kbd>CTRL+U</kbd> `> Unwrap` while still in `Edit-Mode`. Now you have a UV map.
11. Finally apply the texture you created. You should than get distorted paintings.
    Start to re-painting again, only this time you should see your UVs and your material and Your textures.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Hi. I would like to suggest not asking people to accept your answer (when they have not indicated that the answer has helped them) as asking encourages people to accept the *first* answer, not the *best* one. If they comment or indicate the answer has helped, *then* teach them about how accepting works (see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer). Also, regarding adding sign-offs to your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Comment: I'll link on images, all posts where it is demostrated clearly that new users do not know how voting works. I've explained this over and over. I'll include and IF answer works for them, next time.